# GWT Limiting Request

Tags: gwt, producer-consumer

I have two servers A and B which serves images. A is a fast, and B is a slow server.
A doesn't have all images. 
I'm doing a limited browser cache for images.
If the current image requested is at the cache, then I will use it. 
If not, it will call it from A. If it does not have, the image will be requested from B.

But I have another problem. The number of concurrent request to A should be at most M (say 12, browsers also have a limit for this, so it is not so important), and to B should be at most N (say 2, it is important because it is less than browser's limit).

How can I implement such a mechanism?

The problem is like bounded buffer problem in GWT.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this on server side. Tomcat allows you to balance all requests on different servers. See this tutorial: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/loadbalancers.html